# How to change the size of input or select without turning the form "horizontal" in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggling to alter the width of my form controls, the problem is that I end up with some element sliding to the side.
I want to have a layout like this:

```
label //occupies the entire line
short input //occupies the entire line

label //occupies the entire line
short input //occupies the entire line
```

This is the defalt behavior when you use

```
<div class='form-group>
<label class="control-label">some text</label>
 <input class="form-control">
</div>
<div class='form-group>
<label class="control-label">some text</label>
<input class="form-control">
 </div>
```

the problem is when I try to somehow change the width of input or select

Adding the col-md-1 introduces two problems it breaks the text label(that's predictable because col-md-1 resizes the entire container) and make the div inline, even if I wrap the  inside another div it somehow gets out of the div.

```
<div>
<div class='form-group col-md-1'>
<label class="control-label"></label>
<input class="form-control">
</div>
```

If you could give some simple structural example I would be very glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a fiddle so we can see what your problem is. I recreated this and in my example nothing happened, the form-group remained full width.

Perhaps this is what you need

```
<div class=row>

    <div class=col-md-1>

        <div class='form-group'>
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

One thing you need to learn about bootstrap 3 to save yourself some trouble is you are not supposed to mix classes that were not made to be mixed. In the documentation they state very clearly what classes you should use together, and while sometimes it may seem like it's working, in most cases you'd be better off just nesting more elements.

Comment: It laid out the form exactly the way I intended to do. But with the issue of having the label text and input having differents width needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in this way--

**Working Example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
       <style type="text/css">
     
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">           
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
  <div class="form-group">
  
              <label id="label">some text again</label>
              
              <input type="text" class="form-control" > 
              </div>  

   
<div class='form-group'>
   
<label>some text</label>

<input class="form-control">
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Diego Alves: check the snippet the label and input has same width.